# Rank of a matrix with structure

Tags: matrices

Let $P \in [0,1]^{n \times n}$ ($n > 1$) be a matrix such that the diagonal entries $P_{ii} ~~\forall i$ are $0$  and upper diagonal entries $P_{ij} ~~\forall i < j$ $\in (0.5,1)$ and lower diagonal entries $P_{ij} ~~ \forall i > j$ $\in (0,0.5)$.

Is rank($P$) = $n$ always? Or in other words, are the columns of $P$ independent? (This has been answered below in the negative)

What if $P_{ij} + P_{ji} = 1 ~~\forall i \neq j$? Does this restriction help in proving the claim?

Comment: For one thing this fails for $n=1$.

Comment: That's right. Let us assume $n > 1$. It is easy to see this is true for $n = 2$

Comment: With some thought, it can be seen geometrically that this is true even when $n = 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit.** The answer is negative even if the extra condition $p_{ij}+p_{ji}=1$ is imposed. Here is a computer generated counterexample:
$$
P=\frac1{40}\pmatrix{
 0&29&39&38\\
11& 0&37&36\\
 1& 3& 0&22\\
 2& 4&18& 0}.
$$
One can verify that $\det(P)=0, \operatorname{rank}(P)=3$ and $\ker(P)$ is spanned by $(-10, -4, 2, 1)^\top$.

Comment: Thanks! I just got a counter example myself for $n =5$  where the rank is $4$. (though it seems much more contrived!) 

  
 $P = $       \begin{array}{ccccc}
  0 & 0.51 & 0.51 & 0.51 & 0.99 \\
  0.49  & 0 & 0.51 & 0.51 & 0.51 \\
  0.49 & 0.49 & 0 & 0.51 & 0.51 \\
  0.49 & 0.49 & 0.49 & 0 & 0.51 \\
  0.0696 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0
 \end{array} 


The interesting question now is whether it holds with the restriction on $P$ (i.e $P_{ij} + P_{ji} = 1 ~ \forall i \neq j$)

Comment: @Ved What are the precise values of the entries of your $P$? As it stands, $\det(P)=-1344204\times10^{-12}\ne0$.

Comment: The line of reasoning that i used to arrive at the solution is this. The sub matrix $Q=P(1:4,1:4)$ is of rank $4$. Lets add a fifth row $[x^{T} 0]$ where $x \in (0,0.5)^4$ and a fifth column $[y 0]^{T}$ where $y \in (0.5,1)^4$. Now for $P$ to have dependent columns means that $\exists \alpha \in {R}^{5}$ such that $P\alpha = 0$. Using the fact $Q$ is invertible and a bit of algebra, one gets the following necessary condition for $P$ to be rank $4$ : $x^{T}Q^{-1}y = 0$. One can pick $x$ and $y$ that satisfy the above condition.But it isn't clear yet if the same can be done for the 2nd question.

Comment: So  for the second question, we have $x= 1 - y$ where $1$ is the vector of ones. Thus the condition to be satisfied is $y^{T}Q^{-1}y = 1^{T}Q^{-1}y$ where $y \in (0.5,1)^4$. But it is  not clear to me if such a $y$ will exist because i do not know what properties of $Q^{-1}$ will be required to show the claim.

Comment: @Ved I see. The way I constructed my counterexample is the same as yours. ;-D

Comment: Thanks for the counter example! It turns out these matrices have been studied quite a bit in literature under the name '1-hyper tournaments'. One of the sufficient conditions for such matrices to be non singular is that $\|r\|^2_2 < \frac{n^2(n-1)}{4}$ where $r$ is the vector of row sums.  (google for generalized tournaments for further information). It turns out your example indeed does not satisfy this condition!